# Graph API --> receiving empty array of scheduleItems when call POST /me/calendar/getSchedule

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am calling Graph Api endpoint "/me/calendar/getSchedule" to receive schedule for specific room (I am testing in Graph Explorer). Despite of the fact that I have full list of the events including this this room in given timestamps, I receive in scheduleInformation an empty array of scheduledItems.

For test I did the same, but for the user who scheduled this events and it worked perfectly. What could be the reason?

Body req :

```
`{
"schedules": [
        "room@mail.com"
    ],
    "startTime": {
        "dateTime": "2022-12-11T09:00:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "endTime": {
        "dateTime": "2022-12-13T23:59:00",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}`
```

Bopdy resp:

```
`{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Collection(microsoft.graph.scheduleInformation)",
    "value": [
        {
            "scheduleId": "room@mail.com",
            "availabilityView": "000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
            "scheduleItems": []
        }
    ]
}`
```

Event is created in this location , but like there is no relations between what I am creating and the room resources . E.g. thi is an event I have created:

```
 {
        "@odata.etag": "W/\"1z8A//yOl0a9+ObgH9y4KQAAAfmk/Q==\"",
        "id": "some id",
        "subject": "Let's go for lunch",
        "bodyPreview": "Does mid month work for you?",
        "body": {
            "contentType": "html",
            "content": "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\"></head><body>Does mid month work for you?</body></html>"
        },
        "start": {
            "dateTime": "2022-12-13T12:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "end": {
            "dateTime": "2022-12-14T14:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "location": {
            "displayName": "room@mail.com",
            "locationType": "default",
            "uniqueId": "room@mail.com",
            "uniqueIdType": "private"
        },
        "attendees": [],
        "organizer": {
            "emailAddress": {
                "name": "admin",
                "address": "admin@mail.com"
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: If my post doesn't work for you, pls kindly let me know and I'll delete it...

Comment: `for the user who scheduled this events and it worked perfectly` so are you sure the events are belong to this room? just want to confirm if the empty list should be the expected result... thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Well, I use this specific room as a location, so its schedule should not be empty between the timestamps I gave .  I have also tried to use this room as an attendee, but the result is  the same , an empty array scheduleItems. Like there is no relations between what am I doing and the room resources .

Comment: thanks for informing me  this. but since I don't have a test resource so I can't do more investigation on it...

Comment: @Timy Wang what more should I provide to you?

Comment: sorry, those is your private information and you shouldn't provide them with any others... I mean some other commuities may help you...